# "Maintenance of funds" rules for extending UK Tier 2 visas

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I'm currently on a UK Tier 2 General visa, which expires in March 2017. I would expect to continue in my current role with my existing lawyer, at the same level i.e. without a change of the assigned SOC code on my existing Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS).

I was looking ahead on the [eligibility criteria for Tier 2](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/eligibility) which states:

> You must also have £945 in savings - this is to prove you can support
>   yourself. You must have had this in your bank account for 90 days
>   before you apply, **unless you’re exempt**.

Looking at the complete [Tier 2 Policy Guidance document](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/514054/Tier_2_Policy_Guidance_04_2016.pdf), under *Part 7: Points available for Maintenance (Funds)* (on page 40):

> You will be awarded 10 points if: **you currently have entry clearance,
>   leave to enter, or leave to remain as a Tier 2 skilled worker**; work
>   permit holder; Jewish Agency Employee; Member of the Operational
>   Ground Staff of an Overseas-owned Airline; Minister of Religion;
>   Missionary; Member of a Religious Order; or Representative of an
>   Overseas Newspaper, News Agency or Broadcasting Organisation; or

Am I correct to interpret that "Tier 2 skilled worker" above means in my situation, I'm exempt from demonstrating maintenance of funds through cash in my bank account? (Asking because I mostly move all of my spare cash into Stocks and Shares ISAs rather than my current account.)